# Running OSCB and CH tests on pmdarima module - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'

Tags: python, typeerror, linear-regression, normalize

I am doing a Python project of my own hobby. I am struggling to run OSCB and CH tests using pmdarima and I have received the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 6
      3 n_ocsb = pmd.arima.OCSBTest(m=12).estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(df_b_trans['Gold ETF Adj Close'].dropna())
      5 # CH test that returns the recommended order of seasonal differencing:
----> 6 n_ch = pmd.arima.CHTest(m=12).estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(df_b_trans['Gold ETF Adj Close'].dropna())
      8 # seasonal differencing recommendation:
      9 print('Gold ETF Adj Close')

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pmdarima/arima/seasonality.py:362, in CHTest.estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(self, x)
    359 if n < 2 * m + 5:
    360     return 0
--> 362 chstat = self._sd_test(x, m)
    364 if m <= 12:
    365     return int(chstat > self.crit_vals[m - 2])  # R does m - 1...

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pmdarima/arima/seasonality.py:234, in CHTest._sd_test(wts, s)
    231 R1 = CHTest._seas_dummy(wts, s)
    233 # fit model, get residuals
--> 234 lmch = LinearRegression(normalize=True).fit(R1, wts)
    235 # lmch = sm.OLS(wts, R1).fit(method='qr')
    236 residuals = wts - lmch.predict(R1)

TypeError: LinearRegression.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'
```

Below is my code:

```
n_ocsb = pmd.arima.OCSBTest(m=12).estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(df_b_trans['Gold ETF Adj Close'].dropna())

n_ch = pmd.arima.CHTest(m=12).estimate_seasonal_differencing_term(df_b_trans['Gold ETF Adj Close'].dropna())

print('Gold ETF Adj Close')
print('Time series before first differencing -')
n_seasdiffs = {'Recommended order of seasonal differencing':'', "OCSB recommendation":n_ocsb, "nCH recommendation":n_ch}
[print(key, ":", value) for key,value in n_seasdiffs.items()]
```

I am expecting to see below output:

```
Gold ETF Adj Close
time series before first differencing -
recommended order of seasonal differencing : 
OCSB recommendation : 
nCH recommendation :
```